# Something like copy by reference in database

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data

There is a table in my database called Category that I store some Tree structure data in it.

Tree structure means that each row has `parent_id` witch is refers to another row and if `parent_id` was empty means that node does not have any parent. Each category also refers to a user.

example data:

```
id | title     | parent_id | user_id
1  | test      | null      | 1
2  | test_1    | 1         | 1
3  | test_1_1  | 2         | 1
```

Now I want something like copy by reference in database.

For example user1 wants to copy his/her category to user2. In copy by value I select all of user1 's row and insert them for user2. but in copy by reference user2 refers to user1 's category. If any changes occurred in user1 's category, user2 's category will update automatically.

it is like `*` in `c++`.

my question is how can I implement copy by reference in database?

Comment: So, basically you want to duplicate all rows where user_id = 1 and set the user_id to 2?

Comment: no, I want to add one row that refers to user1's category. not copy all of user1's row. just refer to them. maybe I should add another table of something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this. All user use the same categories.

[image]

**Edit: Add Sample Data**

Users:

[image]

Categories:

[image]

UserCategories:

[image]

**Edit2: Add more sample data**
Define more users and more category and you can use mix of them and still all of them refer to the same row.

[image]

Comment: some user wants their own category. for example user1 has category1 and user2 has category2. but user3 want to refer to category2

Comment: Still, this works. You can do that. And also you can use a mix of categories for users.

Comment: If you want, I can show you in the sample data, how you can do that by this structure.